# wordpress media library shows empty images

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I have copied the my old site files and moving those into new site. i have changed the url in db, and uploaded the files in new server. everything works fine except the media show black images .can any one suggest me what is wrong with this.

[image]

Comment: How did you "change" the url in the db? If you just used a search & replace in a text-editor, that will screw up some of the values (like text-widgets).

Comment: @kuchenundkakao yes . i have changed using find and replace in notepad++

Comment: Are image link URL correct in these images. Check URL of any of these empty images and make sure it's correct. Copy paste URL in your browser to check if image is visible.

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks after the migration. That is most of the time the only requirement if you are sure all paths in the db has been changed

Comment: @Roberthue I have copied the image url and checked in browser . it works . But where as in media library it is not showing.

Comment: @PieterGoosen flushed the permalinks . but no use.

Answer (score 2):

Plugins such as [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) can help you to *properly* fix the URLs in your database.

Likewise, consider using backup-and-migration plugins such as [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) (paid) or [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) (free) to properly and more easily move your site (while automatically handling the above search-and-replace operation).